# Label Visibility не обновляется в UI wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть Label, который я хочу показывать по нажатию на кнопку, для этого я добавила Visibility={Binding InfoVisibility}.

UI зависает, так как идет выполнение команды. Я вижу в debug, что property поменялось, но в UI  оно не успевает отобразиться,  и только после завершения выполнения команды, UI thread освобождаеться, Label появляется.

До выполнения команды, Label Visibility is Collapsed

```
    public void FreeFilterCommandAction()
        {
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
            if (_flag)
            {
                 InfoVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
             
                _flag = false;
                SetForgeriesDataExtraction();
            }

            ApplyFilter(_freeFilter != null ? FilterType.FreeFilter : FilterType.None);
         }

private Visibility _infoVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

 public Visibility InfoVisibility
        {
            get => _infoVisibility;
            set
            {
                _infoVisibility = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

```
 <Label Margin="20 0 0 0" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                   Content="Only the first search could take some time. Please, wait ..." 
                   Visibility="{Binding InfoVisibility}"></Label>
```

Label становится видимым только после выполнения команды.
Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы Visibility обновлялось до выполнения  SetForgeriesDataExtraction();.

Comment: Ничего не понятно, но очень интересно... Предположу, что у вас зависает интерфейс и только после выполнения определенной логики меняется видимость, так? Если нет, то я вообще не понял вопроса.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я изменила описание вопроса :-) если, что то еще непонятно говори. Я просто недавно начала пользоваться StackOverFlow, совсем junior

Comment: `UI зависает, так как идет выполнение команды` - воот, это теперь объясняет суть проблемы. А проблема тут в том, что вы запускаете сложную, долгую логику в UI потоке, из-за чего он блокируется. Как исправить? Выполнять эту логику в другом потоке. Самое простое (и наверно лучшее), это использовать `async/await`, запуская тем самым задачу асинхронно. Как запустить? Зависит от того, что в `SetForgeriesDataExtraction()` прописано... А и да, в WPF `Lable` лучше заменить на `TextBlock`. Ну и старайтесь не использовать UI элементы (цвет, видимость и др.) в коде.